# Division by zero while getting divide post result and array sum

Tags: php, codeigniter, models, divide-by-zero

In my Models :

```
function input()
{
    $vendor = $this->input->post('vendor');
    for($i=1;$i<=$vendor;$i++)
    {
        for($j=1;$j<=$vendor;$j++)
        {
            $delivery[$j] = $this->input->post('delivery_1_'.$j.'_'.$i);
            $totalsatu[$i]  = array_sum($delivery);
        }
        for($k=1;$k<=$vendor;$k++)
        {
            $delivery[$k] = $this->input->post('delivery_1_'.$k.'_'.$i);
            $totaldua[$i] = $totalsatu[$i] / $delivery[$k];
        }
    }
    return array
    (
        'result1' => $totalsatu,
        'result2' => $totaldua
    );
}
```

and in my `views`,i call the `$result1` and `$result2` but I keep getting the following error like this :

```
Message: Division by zero

Filename: models/core.php

Line Number: 113
```

Here is the line number of 113 :

```
$totaldua[$i] = $totalsatu[$i] / $delivery[$k];
```

Comment: maybe you get that error because you're really trying to divide by zero

Comment: `$totaldua[$i] =  $delivery[$k] ? $totalsatu[$i] / $delivery[$k] : 0;`

Comment: so check what value `$delivery[$k]` has at that point. maybe it's a string that gets coerced into a 0 "for your convenience"

Comment: To make your life 100% easier, rename your form inputs. Try <input name="delivery[<?=$k?>][<?=$i?>]" /> or such. It'll come back to the server as an array!

Comment: @joeframbach i've named all of the forms with unique name and getting back with an array,like your suggestions,but when i giving back the results into the views,i get that error :)